# Не очищается корзина в Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

При нажатии на кнопку «Очистить корзину» она не очищается. Как починить корзину? ОС — Linux Ubuntu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для очистки корзины текущего пользователя выполните команду в терминале

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/info/* ~/.local/share/Trash/files/*
```